# UITableViewを使ったプログラム内のインスタンス、関数、引数について

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource  {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var dataArray:[Int] = []

    // ボタンが押された時にデータを追加する
    @IBAction func add(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        dataArray.append(dataArray.count)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: UITableViewDataSource プロトコルのメソッド
    // TableView の各セクションのセルの数を返す
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataArray.count
    }

    // 各セルの内容を返す
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // 再利用可能な cell を得る
        let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        // Cellに値を設定する.
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(dataArray[indexPath.row])"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Subtitle \(dataArray[indexPath.row])"

        return cell
    }
}
```

いくつか質問があります。
上記のプログラムで

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
```

このtableViewは関数ですか？それともインスタンスですか？

また

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dataArray.count
}
```

で引数となっているnumberOfRowsInSectionはメソッドだと思うのですが
それがどうして引数になるのですか？

最後にこのプログラムは関数を定義しているだけなのに
どうして実行するのかが分かりません。

たくさんの質問をすいませんがよろしければ
回答を宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!`
>   このtableViewは関数ですか？それともインスタンスですか？

`tableView`は、**プロパティ**（Property）です。その下の`dataArray`と同じ。`@IBOutlet`、`weak`など修飾子が複数ついていますが、それらを外してしまえば、`tableView`はひとつの**変数**です。
たとえていうなら、変数は容器を指し、**インスタンス**は、その内容を指します。質問の文脈からすれば、`tableView`は容器、すなわち変数とみるべきです。
置いてある場所や、使い道によって、同じモノでも、異なる名称になるのは、私たちの日常でよくあることです。Swiftにおいても、クラスや構造体などに属する関数のことを、**メソッド**（Method）、クラスや構造体などに属する変数のことを**プロパティ**と呼びます。
以上から、`tableView`は、プロパティと呼ぶのが妥当です。
なお、プロパティには2種類あり、**格納型プロパティ**（Stored Property）、**計算型プロパティ**（Computed Property）に分かれます。ここでは格納型プロパティを指しています。
そして、プロパティについて勉強していくと、プロパティが単なる変数ではなく、じつはもっと複雑なものだということがわかってきます。学習を重ね、知識を深めていってください。

> `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int`
>   で引数となっている`numberOfRowsInSection`
>   はメソッドだと思うのですが それがどうして引数になるのですか？

メソッドではありません。**ラベル**（Argument Label）です。
関数（メソッド）は、関数の引数にはなりません。ひとまとまりのプログラムを、引数に渡したいことは、ままありますが、そういう用途には、**クロージャ**（Closure）が用意されています。
関数の書式について、基礎部分を説明します。Swiftは、C言語の書式を踏襲したものになっていますが、随所にC言語と異なる箇所があります。
関数の基本書式は、

```
// 定義の書式
func area(width: Float, height: Float) -> Float {
    return width * height
}

// 呼び出す書式
let a = area(100.0, height: 100.0)
```

関数を呼び出すとき、第2引数以降に、ラベル`height`がつくのが、Swiftの特徴です。

※ここでは、Swift2に基づいて説明をしています。Swift3では、第1引数だけ特別扱いするのは、複雑なだけでわかりにくいという意見を取り入れて、第1引数にもラベルがつくようになります。

```
func area(width: Float, height: Float) -> Float {
    return width * height
}

let a = area(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
```

基本書式では、引数名がそのままラベル名になりますが、引数名とラベル名を異なるものにすることが可能です。

```
func area2(width w: Float, height h: Float) -> Float {
    return w * h
}

let b = area2(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
```

ラベル名と引数名を併記して定義します。
質問の`func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int`は、このパターンの書式に該当します。`numberOfRowsInSection`がラベルで、`section`が引数です。
ついでに、いちいち引数にラベルをつけるのは、うざったいと考える向きには、ラベルを省略する書式も用意されています。

```
func area3(w: Float, _ h: Float) -> Float {
    return w * h
}

let c = area3(100.0, 100.0)
```

アンダーバー（_）を使って、省略を指示します。

> 最後にこのプログラムは関数を定義しているだけなのに どうして実行するのかが分かりません。

この点については、**デリゲート**（Delegate）というデザインパターンについて勉強していただく必要があります。iOSのフレームワークにおいては、多用されるデザインパターンですので、いちど腰を据えて学習するだけの価値があります。
とりあえずかんたんに説明します。Delegateは、直訳すると、「委譲」、「委託」となります。
`UITableView`は、いうまでもなくテーブルを表示するViewですが、テーブルを表示するには、まず表示するデータ、セクションの数、セクションごとの行数、行ごとの高さ、セルごとに表示するデータなどなど、多数の要素が決定しないと、なにも始まりません。たとえば、`UIImageView`は、イメージを表示するViewですが、サイズとイメージデータを、インスタンスのプロパティとして代入すれば、イメージが表示されます。`UITableView`でも、いくら必要な要素が多数あるとしても、すべてプロパティに代入すれば、コンテンツの表示はできるはずです。
しかし、`UITableView`は、必要な要素を内部のプロパティに持つのではなく、そのほとんどを、外部の別のインスタンスに委託するという形態を取っています。`UITableView`は、`ViewController`インスタンスに定義してある`func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int`というメソッドを呼び出して、自らのセクションごとの行数を決定します。
このメソッドは「呼ばれていないのに実行される」のではなく、`UITableView`が呼んだので、実行されます。

※C#などでは、Delegateは言語の一部として扱われますが、Swiftはそうではありません。純粋にSwiftに関する書籍、情報だけあたってみても、Delegateに関する記述が見つからないことがあります。iOSや、UIKitに関連づけて検索したほうがいいでしょう。